# Cannot make a mask for BTJD format of a Time object

Tags: python, time, mask

I cannot make a mask using the following code:

`mask = (flat_lc['time'] < 1346) | (flat_lc['time'] > 1350)`

You can see what the dataframe looks like here: [Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okX0F.png)

I get the following error:

`'<' not supported between instances of 'Time' and 'int'`

I think there has been an update recently that has changed this. The tutorial I'm following has their mask like this. I get the same error if I change the mask values to a string instead of an int.

Answer (score 0):

the object flat_lc is a astropy Time object so I checked the documentation for that and found out you can access the values of the object by doing:

`flat_lc['time'].value`

The mask then becomes:

`mask = (flat_lc['time'].value < 1346) | (flat_lc['time'].value>1350)`